# How to find the networks with router:external=True using python-neutronclient in openstack?

Tags: python-2.7, openstack, openstack-neutron

I am trying to find the networks with `router:external=True`.

```
print neutron.list_networks({'name':'route:external','boolean': True})
```

Tried this, but was returning every networks.

```
print neutron.list_networks(tenant_id=xxxx)
```

But in this case, it only returns networks created by specific tenant.
How can I filter and find the external network using python neutron client?

Answer (score 0):

```
neutronclient.list_networks(name='myprivatenetwork')
```

Actual for neutron 6.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge here is that router:external filter parameter can not be interpret as valid function argument, but there is at least one workaround:

I solved this by constructing dictionary with all filter parameters and pass the content of the dictionary as function args to the list_network method:

```
filter_params = {'router:external': True}
networks = neutron.list_networks(retrieve_all=True, **filter_params)
```